# NullPointerException при работе с Volley

Tags: java, android

Очень много тем на эту ошибку. Но очень прошу, если ставите минус к теме, то хотя бы сформируйте комментарий почему вопрос задан не корректно. 
В большинстве случаев, получается отследить и исправить данную проблему, но в случае работы с Volley не могу врубится. 
Вот код вызова

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        Log.v(TAG, "in afterTextChanged");
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (translatedTextInput.getText().length() != 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                            shortLangReference = getSharedPreferences(LANGUAGE_SHORT, MODE_PRIVATE);
                            language = mSettings.getString(LANGUAGE_SHORT, "");
                            translatedInputString = translatedTextInput.getText().toString().replace(" ", "+");
                            UrlBuilder urlBuilder = new UrlBuilder(MainActivity.this, translatedInputString, language);
                            String url = urlBuilder.buildUrl(translatedInputString, language).toString();
                            Log.v(TAG, "url = " + url);
                            SendJsonRequest sendJsonRequest = new SendJsonRequest();
                            sendJsonRequest.translatedJson(url);
                        }
                    });
                }
                InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(translatedTextInput.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }, 600);
    }
```

Вот метод , который должен запускать HTTP запрос

```
public class SendJsonRequest {

    AppCompatEditText translatedTextOutput;
    String translatedInputString;
    final String TAG = "myTag";
    String language;
    String result;
    SharedPreferences mSettings;
    SharedPreferences shortLangReference;
    Context context;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    public SendJsonRequest(Context context, String language, SharedPreferences mSettings,
                           SharedPreferences shortLangReference, String translatedInputString) {
        this.context = context;
        this.language = language;
        this.mSettings = mSettings;
        this.shortLangReference = shortLangReference;
        this.translatedInputString = translatedInputString;

    }

    public SendJsonRequest() {
    }

    public String translatedJson(String url){
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Inside OnResponse" + response.toString());
                        JSONArray results = null;
                        try {
                            results = response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations");
                            for (int i=0,j=results.length();i<j;i++) {
                                String translationTextResult = results.getJSONObject(i).getString("translatedText");
                                result = translationTextResult;
                                translatedTextOutput.setText(translationTextResult);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error :" + e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "NetworkError");
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!");
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "AuthFailureError");
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!");
                        } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "NoConnectionError!");
                        } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.");
                        }
                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
        return result;
    }


}
```

Меня смущает строка, которая отличается от стандартного создания объекта класса

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
```

Ошибка происходит в этих строках

```
requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

И

```
sendJsonRequest.translatedJson(url);
```

Ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.borisruzanov.volleyexample, PID: 30139
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
                  at com.borisruzanov.volleyexample.Service.SendJsonRequest.translatedJson(SendJsonRequest.java:88)
                  at com.borisruzanov.volleyexample.MainActivity$1$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:91)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Вопрос еще в том, что пока я не перенес все в отдельный класс все работало.

P.S. Я знаю, что эти ошибки уже всех достали, и новички, как я. Но если надумаете минуснуть, то хотя бы скорректируйте вопрос, чтобы я знал, как его задавать в следующий раз и сэкономить ваше время:)

Comment: NPE малоинформативное исключение, а вы ещё предлагаете нам гадать где он выскочил. Укажите конкретную строку. Только не номер, а именно строку

Comment: Выведите `context` перед вызовом `Volley.newRequestQueue(context);`. Подозреваю, что вы эту переменную ничем не инициализировали, и там `null`. А лучше покажите код класса `Activity` вашей.

Comment: Да, контекст у вас `null`. Заметить надо `context` на `MainActivity.this` в строке `requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);`

Comment: @Suvitruf , добавил больше кода. Попробовал заменить на mainactivity.this , все равно та же ошибка. Но спасибо всем за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас `RequestQueue requestQueue;` нигде не инизиализировано, вот оно на `requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);` и падает.

**P.S.** вы создаёте класс `SendJsonRequest` с пустым конструктором:

```
SendJsonRequest sendJsonRequest = new SendJsonRequest();
sendJsonRequest.translatedJson(url);
```

У вас там ни `context`, ни `mSettings` и т.п. не инициализированы.

Как надо?

Такой конструктор:

```
public SendJsonRequest(Context context, RequestQueue queue, String language, SharedPreferences mSettings,
                           SharedPreferences shortLangReference, String translatedInputString) {
        this.context = context;
        this.language = language;
        this.mSettings = mSettings;
        this.shortLangReference = shortLangReference;
        this.translatedInputString = translatedInputString;
        this.requestQueue = queue;
}
```

А вместо этого:

```
SendJsonRequest sendJsonRequest = new SendJsonRequest();
sendJsonRequest.translatedJson(url);
```

Это:

```
SendJsonRequest sendJsonRequest = new SendJsonRequest(context, requestQueue, language, mSettings, shortLangReference, translatedInputString);
sendJsonRequest.translatedJson(url);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите, инициализировать ее в mainactivity верно? или в классе, где находится метод?

Comment: Во-первых, надо создавать `SendJsonRequest ` не с конструктором по умолчанию. Во-вторых, в этот конструктор ещё добавить `RequestQueue ` и передавать созданный  `requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)` туда.

Comment: @BorisRuzanov я обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое за потраченное время. Я и использовал изначально конструктор такой же, но на одном моменте решил использовать по умолчанию. Теперь логично, что образец пустой создается. Буду пробовать. Отпишу позднее и обозначу решение. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: и еще вопрос, если использовать этот метод класса несколько раз в других класса. Можно ли как либо избежать постоянной инициализации language, mSettings, shortLangReference, translatedInputString? Избежать дубляжа кода

Comment: @BorisRuzanov можно сделать класс статическим и инициализировать его один раз, как пример. Но это не очень хорошо, так как ссылки могут занулиться в процессе работы, после поворота экрана например.

Comment: поэтому в данном случае всегда инициализировать отдельно всегда?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov а вам вообще экземпляр класса этого точно нужен? Можно метод объявить статическим и в него параметры прокидывать.

Comment: я тогда объявляю статическим и уже вызывая метод могу не создавать экземпляр класса, верно? Тогда метод нужно переделывать верно?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov верно.